# ASP.NET username/password security

Tags: asp.net

I'm using VS2010,C#,SQL Server to develop my ASP.NET web app, although this is not my first ASP.NET experience, but this time my project is more attack-prone and I should consider better security polices. I have a login screen as my first page, users enter their user name and password and a page specific to them is showed, in my last project, I used query strings (a userid) along with sessions for security purposes, but this time I've used just query strings, it means that at the moment one can enter myaddress.com?userid=1 and visit a page in my site!!!
I know this is not good, but what are my approaches, of courses I'm not working with banking or financial systems but I'm going to have an standard security policy, I should use sessions? cookies? can you suggest me an easy-to-develop and meanwhile secure way of implementing protection policies? any sample code or tips?

thanks

Comment: If you are passing URL parameters get away from passing integers like that, someone can easily overcome that.  Look at URL rewriting, or making use of some GUID's.  Remember sessions are good for each incoming user, they are a good part of the web experience.

Comment: URL rewriting and GUID seem good approaches, is there any short way of implementing them?

Comment: I don't know if you are securing fort knox (the app must not be hacked!) or your grocery list (we would be annoyed by hacking), but you will want to use an in memory, encrypted cookie, preferrably managed by ASP.NET's membership feature to track identity between requests and during a request you want to use the Thread principal and/or ASP.NET intrinsic User object.  A URL is subject to replay attacks, lacks any built in expiration mechanism, can be circulated by users to other users by accident or intention, etc.So -1 to the suggestions of putting ID on the URL unless this is a grocery list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET actually comes with all of the facilities you need to provide a secure site out of the box so you don't have to worry about all of these things yourself.

Use the built-in [ASP.NET Membership features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) and you'll be fine.

Comment: +1 - keep it simple and concentrate your efforts more on your business application rather then the security behind it.  Good starting point.